# Difference between date.getHours() and date.hours in AS3 ?

Tags: actionscript-3, date, apache-flex, timezone

```
var date:Date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000); // converts to GMT
trace(date.hours);
trace(date.getHours());
```

I need hours in GMT.  Should I use date.hours ?  or should I use date.getHours() ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not convert the date object and plain get [`date.hoursUTC`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#hoursUTC).

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly explained on the manual:
hours is a property:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#hours

getHours a function / method of de Date Object
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#getHours()

You can easily retrieve the date for different zones with PHP

[date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

and format it with the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (Date/Time Functions)

Comment: I hope this will help you. @Rizwan_Khan